# Android usb stream monitor?

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I am trying to debug an Android app that talks to a usb device. It would be useful to see a log of all usb comms. Does such a facility exist in the os?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not.  I have the Android system source building now for my target, so I can add in my own hooks to stream this data.